# didEnterRegion and didExitRegion don't work in iOS8

Tags: swift, ios8, location

I'm using Core Location to track a region in order to detect if the user enters o exits this region.

Unfortunately, my code works in iOS7, but not in iOS8.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
func setMonitoredRegion() {
var startLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +52.53753000, longitude: +13.35971000)        
    var monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: startLocation, radius: 100, identifier: "Region Test")
    locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(monitoredRegion) 
}
```

The region starts to be tracked in the delegate method didStartMonitoringForRegion:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    println("Starting monitoring \(region.identifier)")
}
```

But in iOS8 the methods didEnterRegion and didExitRegion are not called:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    println("Entered Region \(region.identifier)")
    self.showAlertViewWithTitle("Enter Region", message: "The user has entered in monitored region").show()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didExitRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    println("Exited Region \(region.identifier)")
    self.showAlertViewWithTitle("Exit Region", message: "The user has left monitored region").show()
}
```

Also, I don't receive any error in:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, monitoringDidFailForRegion region: CLRegion!, withError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Or:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

In iOS8 I have included the following key into the info.plist file:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and in code I obtain user authorization:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to get this working by setting "**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**" in my .plist file.

I'm not really sure if that will raise battery usage when the app is not running, but that allowed me to be notified on Entry and on Exit...

Comment: Those entry and exit methods will trigger with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or not??

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to activate the notify-properties:

```
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
```

Comment: I have used it with my CLCircularRegion region before locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(monitoredRegion) with it doesn't work. :(